# IndexOutOfRange error when filling a List Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

Assuming that  Seq1 = "ACACT" Seq2 = "AAT"
why does this code output indexOutOfRange

```
    s1 = len(self.Seq1)
    s2 = len(self.Seq2)
    self.M  = [[0 for x in range(s1)] for y in range(s2)]
    self.Ix = [[0 for x in range(s1)] for y in range(s2)]
    self.Iy = [[0 for x in range(s1)] for y in range(s2)]
    for i in range(s1):
        for j in range(s2):
            if i == 0 and j != 0:
                self.M[i][j]= - math.inf #Error in this line

            if i != 0 and j == 0:
                self.M[i][j]= - math.inf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the *outer* list comprehension determines the number of rows, which equals `len(s2)`:

```
M  = [[0 for x in range(s1)] for y in range(s2)]
```

Yet, when you assign, you use `range(s1)` for row indexing:

```
for i in range(s1):
    for j in range(s2):
        if ....:
            M[i][j] = ...
```

So either reverse the order of your construction of `M`, or reverse the order of assignment to `M[j][i]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because your second word has more letters than the first word.

Maybe you should do something like this:

```
# before: self.M  = [[0 for x in range(s1)] for y in range(s2)] 
self.M  = [[0 for x in range(s2)] for y in range(s1)]
```

Or you should check lengths of words before the loops.